# Django edit comment

Tags: python, django

So i want to do a edit existing comment, but it gives me this error

> ValueError at /episode/Dragon-Ball-Super/edit/11
>   The view home.views.edit_comment didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

edit_comment

```
def edit_comment(request, slug, id):
    anime = get_object_or_404(Anime, slug=slug)
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=id)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=comment.user)
    if request.method == 'POST' or 'NONE':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('anime_title', slug=slug)
        else:
            form = CommentForm()
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'home/edit-comment.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
re_path(r'^episode/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.anime_title, name='anime_title'),
re_path(r'^episode/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/comment/$', views.add_comment, name='add_comment'),
re_path(r'^episode/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/(?P<id>\d+)/?', views.edit_comment, name='edit_comment'),
```

]

link under existing comment

```
{% if comment.user == request.user.userprofile %}
    <h6 class="small comment-meta">
     <a href="{% url 'edit_comment' slug=anime.slug id=comment.id %}">Edit</a>
                    Delete</h6>
{% endif %}
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    anime = models.ForeignKey(Anime, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

edit-comment.html

```
    {% extends 'base/base.html' %}
    {% block head %}
        <title>Edit Comment</title>
    {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
        <h2>Edit Comment</h2>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation in the view, this question is impossible to answer until you do.

Comment: Changed the request.method and now its just not saving edited comment.

Comment: Why did you do that? I said to fix the indentation of the code you've posted here, not introduce a new bug.

Answer (score 2):

You are handling only the POST request. GET request will be placed the first time when you load the form.

```
def edit_comment(request, slug, id):
    anime = get_object_or_404(Anime, slug=slug)
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=id)
    form = CommentForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance=comment.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('anime_title', slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'home/edit-comment.html', {'form':form})
```